# Is this Quercus coccifera?

Tags: species-identification, botany

This specie grows in a dry hilly area in the south of France close to Marseille. I made the picture today. It is quite dominant and grow close to the soil maybe about 50cm.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**. That is definitely a Kermes Oak / quercus Coccifera.

It should start blooming in a week or two, in case you're still in the area by then I recommend checking it out.

It is thriving in that area specifically *because* it's a dry area, otherwise they tend to be pushed out by Holm Oaks / Quercus ilex.

The combination of the area (see below), habitat (dry hills) and picture (especially the acorn cupule) are pretty conclusive and support your original assumption.

[image: Distribution Map]

Comment: also the inferior side of the leaf is usually hairy for _ilex_ not for _coccifera_